# Office files only open with Run as Admin

Tags: windows, windows-10, microsoft-office

I fixed my registry issues using `CCleaner`. after that my office files such as *.docx and so on will not open.

I must open them through the main word app which is `ran as administrator`.
Or I should run CMD as `admin` and then via CMD open the office file.

what should I do in such a case?

Comment: What exactly did you fix about the registry? Ccleaner registry tools are known to cause significant harm to your system. My suggestion is reinstall Office after using the Office uninstallation tool

Comment: You do NOT need to be an admin to open Office files. Never. Your registry changes have hosed your OS. The registry is not a user tool

Comment: If you have enabled System Restore, rollback to before you have damaged Windows with these registry deletes. CCleaner is a pretty dangerous tool - the registry will work fine without cleaning. Otherwise, [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: @harrymc - Reinstalling Windows isn’t an acceptable solution, that’s not a solution, for every problem thus the reason we need more information from the author

Comment: @Ramhound: Why reinstall Windows? In-place Upgrade will probably be enough to restore the missing pieces.

Comment: @davidpostill I definitely agree with harrymc here. The solution is simply to go to control panel, add remove software, select office, and do a quick repair.

Comment: @harrymc Office has a quick repair option since version 2013 that solves this kind of problem. Easier than to do an inplace upgrade or other windows thing. There's also the online repair, which is useful to fix damaged files too. (its basically reinstalling office)

Comment: @LPChip: Good idea. Mine should only be done if yours fails (if the problem is not only with Office).

Comment: Agreed, its a good backup plan.

Comment: If a repair install works, great. But if the registry damage caused damage to the User Profile, repair will not fix it

Comment: What is the specific situation when you can't open Office files? Are there any error screenshots? Repairing reinstalling Office is a common method. Also, whether you backed up the registry.

Answer (score 0):

Since Microsoft Office 2013 and up, you can repair office by doing the following:

Right-click the start menu button, and select the first option, `Apps and Components`.

Scroll down to the bottom, or find it on the right if the window is wide enough:

Related Settings, Programs and Features.

Find your Microsoft Office in the list and select the item. If you have more than one versions, click the one you use. Usually the newest. For example, if you installed Office 2013 and 2016, you may find both in the list, and you may also find multiple entries if you have different languages installed. It doesn't hurt to perform this action on all items of the same version in case you have doubts, although it should work if you just choose one.

Once highlighted, at the top, choose Change.

Office will now guide you through a repair, and will give you two options.

Quick repair and Online Repair.

Quick repair will repair anything like registry and this is the one you want to take.

Online repair will go a step further and performs a complete uninstall/reinstall of Office. Be careful here, because if you select this one, you will have to enter your office license code again. This is not a problem if you use an Office365 subscription, as you then just have to login with your account. But if your office is not tied to an account and you don't know your license code, this option is not recommended.

If quick repair fails to do the job, but you are certain you have your office license key available, you can try the online repair.

If that fails too, you can try a [windows in-place upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) as a last resort.

Comment: I uninstalled the office and re-installing it again. It fixed